# Code completion in Xcode

Tags: xcode, code-completion

When you type the name of an object in Xcode and press escape to activate code completion, is there any way to only view the direct methods of that object.

At the moment I can see hundreds of different methods. Why are those methods even there? They can't all belong to the parent object (NSObject in this case)?

And why can I see properties of the object appearing as methods? I wouldn't be surprised to the property's get or set methods (confusingly they are nowhere to be seen) but why does the property of the object itself appear as a method?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using (3 or 4)?

Comment: I'm not OP but would like the answer for Xcode 4 if that's possible. Shame OP didn't bother to keep an eye on his question

Answer (score 0):

use "command + ." to achieve the direct methods of that object.